# COM Out of Process Server (CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER) implemented as MFC modal dialog fails

Tags: com

I have created a COM out of process server. This server is a default modal dialog box with two button "OK" and "Cancel".

This is how i register the out-of process COM Server in the  CCostTestApp::InitInstance()

```
BOOL CCostTestApp::InitInstance()
{
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
// Set this to include all the common control classes you want to use
// in your application.
InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

CWinApp::InitInstance();

AfxEnableControlContainer();

// Standard initialization
// If you are not using these features and wish to reduce the size
// of your final executable, you should remove from the following
// the specific initialization routines you do not need
// Change the registry key under which our settings are stored
// TODO: You should modify this string to be something appropriate
// such as the name of your company or organization
SetRegistryKey(_T("Local AppWizard-Generated Applications"));

//**Registering Out-of Process COM Server**
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);     

CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);

// Let's see if we were started by SCM.
//if(strstr(lpCmdLine, "/Embedding") || strstr(lpCmdLine, "-Embedding"))
if(cmdInfo.m_bRunEmbedded == TRUE)
{
    CCostTestFactory costFactory;

    HRESULT hr = CoRegisterClassObject(CLSID_CostTest, (IClassFactory*)&costFactory, 
        CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE, &m_RegID);
    if ( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        CoUninitialize();
        return FALSE;
    }
}


CCostTestDlg dlg;
m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
if (nResponse == IDOK)
{
    // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
    //  dismissed with OK
}
else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
{
    // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
    //  dismissed with Cancel
}

// Since the dialog has been closed, return FALSE so that we exit the
//  application, rather than start the application's message pump.

return FALSE;
```

}

I am creating a client for this COM server as a console exe, from which i will be querying the interface.

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

IUnknown* pIUnknow = NULL;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CostTest, NULL , CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IUnknown, (void**)&pIUnknow);
if (NULL == pIUnknow)
{   
    cout<< "NULL Interface";
}
CoUninitialize();
return 0;
```

Now, CoCreateInstance fails, with the error "Server Execution Failed."

I Debuged, the server code, and found that server gets registered properly as  CoRegisterClassObject() returns S_OK and i get the class object.

However, after this, when it tries to create the dialog box, using DoModal(), it pumps messages into the loop, the first message with the id "49214" is sucessfull after this it tries to pump another message with the id "1024". This throws an exception "Unhandled exception at 0xffffffff in CostTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation."

I am totally lost as I am implementing a COM Server for the first time.

Also, if I create the COM Server as a simple console exe, it works!!!.

Please help me understand.

Comment: @HansPassant: I know how to use debugger. I just dont know why is it behaving in this manner. Any tips would be helpful.

Comment: @HansPassant: Am I missing any initialization or probably we cannot have a dialog box open through a COM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> {
>     CCostTestFactory costFactory;
>
>     HRESULT hr = CoRegisterClassObject(CLSID_CostTest, (IClassFactory*)&costFactory, 
>         CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE, &m_RegID);
> }
> ```

You give the COM runtime a pointer to a local variable. Very soon afterwards, that variable goes out of scope and is destroyed, leaving the system with a dangling pointer. Then later the system calls a method through that dangling pointer, and **boom**.

Comment: Thank for you help, it solved the problem. However, since I will be creating the CCostTestFactory on heap, ExitInstance() will be the best place to clean it, am i right?

Comment: Normally, you would `CoRevokeClassObject` during your application's shutdown; `ExitInstance` would be a reasonable place to do that. In response to `CoRevokeClassObject`, the system will `Release` the pointer it was holding on to, which should result in the reference count on the object reaching zero. This is a cue for a typical COM object to destroy itself.